multiple level ordering of a data.table (mixed data of characters and numbers)
This is my sample data.
patients = c("1A","10A","11A","2B","2C","22C","3A","3B","A1","2");
study= c("1a",2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,1);
treatment = c("10mg","1mg","2g","3mcg","6mcg","a","a","b","f",5);
DT = data.table(study,patients,treatment);

I would like this data.table to be ordered by multiple levels as defined by user.
User input is imported from somewhere. sometimes it can be 3 items or 2 but atleast 1 item. this is a sample input of two vectors to be focused for ordering. this can be any order of level for example first study then patients or first patients and then study.
input = c("study","patients");

commands which I have tried are:

This works well, but i would like to make it dynamic by incorporating input object.

DT[mixedorder(patients,study,decreasing = FALSE)];


for some reason setorderv of data.table package doesn't works on my original data.

please I prefer mixedorder.
I would not like it to be converted to data.frame, and dont want to use dplyr package.
sorting should on a vector/s which is a mix of character, numbers or/and both.
further explanation why mixedorder is preferred.
I am still looking for a better answer.
for this data:
DT<-data.table(values = c(rnorm(100),2:11),
           sortcol1 = c(paste0("ASORT", sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)),1:10),
           sortcol2 = c(paste0("BSORT", sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE)),5:14),
           stringsAsFactors = F)


input = c("sortcol2","sortcol1");

the two different way of ordering would give different results and my preference is ordering as done by mixedorder.
1)
DT[mixedorder(sortcol2,sortcol1 , decreasing = FALSE)]


2)
setorderv(DT,input)



We can aim at the integers generated when factorizing a vector. To get the desired level order, we can use gtools::mixedsort to provide sorted levels. Using Map we can do this for multiple columns. (We need this detour bacause gtools::mixedorder is written differently than base::order.) Next we use order on multiple columns. Since the input <- is character, we need to use mget with function name 'order' in do.call.
> DT2
    study patients treatment
   <char>   <char>    <char>
1:     1a       1A      10mg
2:      1      10A       1mg
3:     11      11A        2g
4:      1       2B      3mcg
5:      2       2C      6mcg
6:      1      22C         a
7:      2       3A         a

> input <- c('study', 'patients')

> u <- 1:3  ## define columns to factorize
> DT2[u] <- Map(factor, DT2[u], lapply(DT2[u], unique) |> lapply(gtools::mixedsort))

> DT2[with(DT2, do.call('order', mget(input))), ]
    study patients treatment
   <fctr>   <fctr>    <fctr>
1:      1       2B      3mcg
2:      1      10A       1mg
3:      1      22C         a
4:     1a       1A      10mg
5:      2       2C      6mcg
6:      2       3A         a
7:     11      11A        2g

If we were to use data.table::setorderv—aiming at the traditional alphabetic order—it changes the data in place, i.e. don't use it in brackets.
> setorderv(DT2, input)
> DT2
    study patients treatment
   <fctr>   <fctr>    <fctr>
1:      1       2B      3mcg
2:      1      10A       1mg
3:      1      22C         a
4:     1a       1A      10mg
5:      2       2C      6mcg
6:      2       3A         a
7:     11      11A        2g


Data:
library(data.table)
DT2 <- data.table(study=c("1a", "1", "11", "1", "2", "1", "2"),
                  patients=c('1A', '10A', '11A', '2B', '2C', '22C', '3A'),
                  treatment=c('10mg', '1mg', '2g', '3mcg', '6mcg', 'a', 'a'))


is their any way, we can get same result by using mixedorder from gtools package,

@Mohit Yes, see update please.

this seems ok, but will not work if there is any column which is number only. for e.g. if we use this on my other dataset in the question. the error is  Cannot assign 'factor' to 'double'. Factors can only be assigned to factor, character or list columns.

@Mohit That's right, your toy data didn't include numerics though. Try to combine with the linked order approach. At least you've learned how to use setorderv and mixedsort. I'll leave the rest to you.

Thanks, I have btw given 2 different datasets in my question. i dont think I can use setorderv or order' your answer seems good but if only it could include numeric column as well.

I am fine to tick this answer and open another question with full details in the question. I understand i have made multiple requests.

@Mohit Sure, good luck!
